# Updating Parent List Screen from Add Item Screen Displayed in a Modal in SwiftUI (MVVM)

Tags: swiftui

I have two screens. CoffeeOrderListScreen and AddCoffeeOrderScreen. CoffeeOrderListScreen lists all the coffee orders and also open a modal to show AddCoffeeOrderScreen. My question is when I am adding a new item to an API how can my AddCoffeeOrderScreen tell CoffeeOrderListScreen to refresh.

```
struct CoffeeOrderListScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: CoffeeOrderListViewModel
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(vm.orders) { order in
            Text(order.name)
        }.task {
            do {
                try await vm.loadOrders()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Orders")
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Add Order") {
                        isPresented = false 
                    }
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                AddCoffeeOrderScreen(vm: AddCoffeeOrderViewModel(httpClient: HTTPClient.shared))
            })
    }
}
```

The implementation of AddCoffeeOrderViewModel is shown below:

```
@MainActor
class AddCoffeeOrderViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var httpClient: HTTPClient
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var coffeeName: String = ""
    @Published var total: Double = 0.0
    @Published var size: CoffeeSize = .medium
        
    init(httpClient: HTTPClient) {
        self.httpClient = httpClient
    }
    
    func placeOrder() async throws {
        
        let coffeeOrder = CoffeeOrder(name: name, coffeeName: coffeeName, total: total, size: size)
        let coffeeOrderData = try JSONEncoder().encode(coffeeOrder)
        
        let resource = Resource(url: APIs.addOrder.url, method: .post(coffeeOrderData), modelType: CoffeeOrder.self)
        let savedCoffeeOrder = try await httpClient.load(resource)
        // How do I tell CoffeeOrderListViewScreen that a new order has been added.
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)  
In essence, you should have only **one** `@StateObject var vm = CoffeeOrderListViewModel()` in `CoffeeOrderListScreen` 
that you pass to the other views directly (`@ObservedObject var vm: CoffeeOrderListViewModel`) or using `@EnvironmentObject var vm: CoffeeOrderListViewModel` and `.environmentObject(vm)`. Similarly for other view models. Just copy and paste the example code.

Answer (score 1):

First there is a problem, you can't init objects in body like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
    AddCoffeeOrderScreen(vm: AddCoffeeOrderViewModel(httpClient: HTTPClient.shared))
})
```

It would be best to remove the view model Combine object entirely since you aren't using a Combine pipeline anyway. Move the place order async func into a OrderController class with custom EnvironmentKey (see then built-in [authorizationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/authorizationcontroller) to get the idea), then you can have a task like:

```
@Environment(\.orderController) var orderController

.task(id: placingOrder) {
    if placingOrder = false {
        return
    }
    do {
        placed = await orderController.placeOrder(order)
    }
    catch {
        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription 
    }
    placingOrder = false
}
```

And a Button to set placingOrder true and and change the button text to cancel.